# Are network bridges still in use today?

Tags: bridge

I've been wondering if bridge is still used by today , because i rarely seen it .Are there any networks thing such as bridge that replace bridge for today? If bridge still used by today what kind of brans that used?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Questions of this type should be avoided from this site since they engage chatty discussion. Please take a look at the [rules](https://serverfault.com/help) before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The term "bridge" has changed over time.  Any device that performs the function of a bridge, namely forwarding frames based on layer 2 addresses, can be considered a bridge.  In this sense, all network switches are essentially bridges, in that they perform this same function.

The only real difference between the original concept of a bridge and modern network switches is that a switch has many more ports than a traditional bridge -- but the function is the same.

Comment: Plus virtual bridges, used in many scenarios.

Comment: Can we still found bridges in the electronic store / online store?

Comment: I have not seen one in over 20 years.